# google map isn't loaded until changing the window size

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a php file that contains Google map. I use bootstrap modal, when the modal loaded, Google map must have been shown inside modal, but unfortunately not. But if I resize the window it will be shown. I mean for the first time that modal loaded, it shows us just gray canvas.

What’s wrong with it?
Any help would be appreciated.

```
 function showCurrent(s){

if(navigator.geolocation){

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(s);
}

}

var position={};
function getCurrentPos(pos){

position['latitude']=pos.coords.latitude;
position['longitude']=pos.coords.longitude;
return position;
  }   
function locationOfIncident(id){

    showCurrent(getCurrentPos);


    var lat=position.latitude;
    latIncident=lat;
    var lon=position.longitude;
    lonIncident=lon;
    var mapOption={
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
        zoom:15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map1= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('location_incident'+id),mapOption);

    marker1= new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
            map:map1,
            draggable:true,
            title:'Location of Incident'
        });

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker1,'dragend',function(res){
       latIncident=res.latLng.lat();
       lonIncident=res.latLng.lng();
       getAddress(latIncident,lonIncident,id);
   });
  }
 HTML////
 <div class="modal fade" id="cat_id_3" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-body">
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="location_incident3"  style="height:200px;">
                    <script>
                        locationOfIncident('3');
                    </script>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: you need to initialize the google map inside modal `shown` event, it will fix this problem `$('#cat_id_3').on('shown.bs.modal', function () { //google map initializing code});`

Comment: @Shehary. unfortunately doesn't work. the same problem

Comment: Almost sure the map container has no width/height in time of creation. Make sure the element is visible and has layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the Google map is initiated

```
 var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('location_incident'+id),mapOption);
```

It'll try to render a map in the size of your parent container. But from your code, it looks like, when your code is executed,

```
<script>locationOfIncident('3');</script>
```

the parent div's height and width are zero, since the modal is shown only after you open the modal(otherwise, it's hidden).

Solution: On the modal show event, ie:

> shown.bs.modal

Trigger map resize event:

```
google.maps.event.trigger({{map name}}, 'resize');
```

Comment: I do it but no results.
$('#cat_id_3').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {google.maps.event.trigger({map1}, 'resize');});
               locationOfIncident('3');

Comment: Well, I had the same issue on a project of mine, in bootstrap accordions though. I'll copy your code and check it my PC.

Comment: it doesn't go inside `$('#cat_id_3').on('shown.bs.modal',function(){
alert();
google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
});`
I mean it doesn't fire even the alert(); it doesn't go inside shown.bs.modal.  what wrong with it?

Comment: $(document).ready( function() {
    $('#cat_id_3').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        setTimeout( function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger( map1, 'resize');
        }, 1000);
    });
});
Try it like this

Comment: :) Hi, BTW, I think, it's better to use some other logic than placing
`<script>locationOfIncident('3')</script>`
inside your modal, because the function will be executed when the browser parses that piece of the DOM, but the javaScript object **google.maps** might not be available then(if the network is slow)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work , but if I click on modal btn twice , it works on the second times,
`$(document).ready(function(){ 
                                $('#cat_id_1').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                                    setTimeout(function(){
                                        locationOfIncident('1');
                                    google.maps.event.trigger(map,"resize");
                                    },10);
                                    

                                });
                            });`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ess_ess/hz9bnfo9/ Well, take a look at this, this is what I was trying to say :) order of writing script is also important. I would place that script in some external file and load it before I refer google maps.
I'm not sure how to do that with jsfiddle, that's whay I wrapped it in  <script id="myScript"></script>